Does application of epsilon delta definition for limits of a real function not require the archimedian property at all?
I believe it doesn't but it could be I am wrong.
If we have a sequence $ \{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ then the archimedian property plays a central role in proving the limit. For instance, let $\epsilon$ be an arbitary non zero real number, then by a well known corollary of the archimedian property, we have that there exists an $N_{\epsilon}$ such that:
$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon} < N_{\epsilon}$$
We then claim that this is the $ N_{\epsilon}$ required to satisfy the epsilon criteria. I also notice that pretty much every proof of epsilon criteria I've done required some sort of use of archimedean property.
However, I think this is completly unnecessary for epsilon delta criterion. For example let us prove that $x^2$ is continous at any point a $x=a$ in the domain. We  can let,  $$\delta = \min\left(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{2|x_0| + 1}\right)$$
In the answer explaining it, it can be seen that no mention of archimedian property is there. The construction seems to be well defined as a consequence of the field structure of $\mathbb{R}$.
If I am indeed correct, then would it be a correct inference to make that epsilon delta proofs in some non trivial sense require less to prove than the epsilon criteria?

Do you need the Archimedean property to define the real numbers?

I am not an expert on its consstruction. I understand it simply as a field with some properties @Peter

The real numbers have the Archimedean property. There are non-Archimedean valuations on the rational numbers, and when they are used to complete the rational field you get a complete field which is different from the field of real numbers. Do a Google search for "non archimedean valuation".

Understood @Peter but nowhere did I argue against real numbers having the Archimedean property

The $1/n$ example only requires the Archimedean property, if you require $N_{\epsilon}$ is an integer.

Well convergence of sequence expects you to find an integer for an epsilon@Steen82

$\epsilon=0$ would be a counterexample to the second sentence of your question.

Epsilon greater than 0 @Snared

The question says $\epsilon \in \mathbb R$, not $\epsilon \in \mathbb R^{>0}$.

where did I say that? Being a field means that every non zero element has a multiplicative inverse @Snared

"let ϵ be an arbitary real number". The third sentence in your question is false.

Not the second but the third

Your observation is right on target, since the proof you gave is just as valid over hyperreals ${}^\ast\mathbb R$ as over reals $\mathbb R$, by the transfer principle.  As is well known, hyperreal fields are not Archimedean.

A tangential point but nonetheless of interest:
After some discussing with my peers, I find that we can sort of reformulate the epsilon delta via the archimedian property.
First we recall the archimedian property $\forall \epsilon \exists N  :\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$, and with some work we can turn epsilon delta  of a limit to:
$$\forall N_{\epsilon} \exists  N_{\delta } : |x-a| < \frac{1}{ N_{\delta } } \implies |f(x)- f(a)| < \frac{1}{ N_{\epsilon}}$$
Where $N_{\epsilon}, N_{\delta} \in \mathbb{N}$
